# Alexa Skill Lambda Node.js dynamic intents in handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Is it possible to dynamically fill the intents in the lambda function of an alexa skill? For example:

```
const handlers = {
var intentName = this.event.request.intent.name;
'LaunchRequest': function () {
    this.emit(':ask', welcomeOutput, welcomeReprompt);
},
'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
    speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.HelpIntent.';
    reprompt = '';
    this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, reprompt);
},
'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
    speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.CancelIntent';
    this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
},
'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
    speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.StopIntent.';
    this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
},
'SessionEndedRequest': function () {
    speechOutput = '';
    //this.emit(':saveState',true);//uncomment to save attributes to db on session end
    this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
},
'ci_clothing': function () {
    speechOutput = '';

    speechOutput = "Here is the output";
    this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, speechOutput);
},}


exports.handler = (event, context) => {
   const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
   alexa.appId = APP_ID;
   // To enable string internationalization (i18n) features, set a resources object.
   //alexa.resources = languageStrings;
   alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
   //alexa.dynamoDBTableName = 'DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME'; //uncomment this line to save attributes to DB
   alexa.execute();};
```

For example if I wanted to have the 'ci_clothing' intent dynamically. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The only thing you need is a helper function which creates all handlers. Afterwards use this helper function to `registerHandlers`.

Something like that:

```
const getHandlers = (request) => {
    const intentName = request.intent.name;
    return {
        'LaunchRequest': function () {
            this.emit(':ask', welcomeOutput, welcomeReprompt);
        },
        'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
            speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.HelpIntent.';
            reprompt = '';
            this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, reprompt);
        },
        'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
            speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.CancelIntent';
            this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
        },
        'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
            speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.StopIntent.';
            this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
        },
        'SessionEndedRequest': function () {
            speechOutput = '';
            //this.emit(':saveState',true);//uncomment to save attributes to db on session end
            this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
        },
        [intentName]: function () {
            speechOutput = '';

            speechOutput = "Here is the output";
            this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, speechOutput);
        },
    };
};

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.appId = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(getHandlers(event.request));
    alexa.execute();
};
```

**Disclaimer**: It's not tested

Edit:

But I think it's not best practice to overwrite all your handlers. You should definitely use the Built-In intents and not your "rule them all" intent. Accordingly you should do a small change within `getHandlers` :

```
const getHandlers = (request) => {
    const intentName = request.intent.name;
    const handlers = {
        'LaunchRequest': function () {
            this.emit(':ask', welcomeOutput, welcomeReprompt);
        },
        'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
            speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.HelpIntent.';
            reprompt = '';
            this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, reprompt);
        },
        'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
            speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.CancelIntent';
            this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
        },
        'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
            speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.StopIntent.';
            this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
        },
        'SessionEndedRequest': function () {
            speechOutput = '';
            //this.emit(':saveState',true);//uncomment to save attributes to db on session end
            this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
        },
    };

    if (!handlers[intentName]) {
        handlers[intentName] = function () {
            speechOutput = '';

            speechOutput = "Here is the output";
            this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, speechOutput);
        };
    }

    return handlers;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your first solution is exactly what I need :-). My intention is to handle lots of intens dynamically. So, for example, I get the Intention Name and look for the answer in a JSON-File.